# Python: ValueError: 2 is not in list

Tags: python, list, mongodb

I am beginner to python and I am stuck with this error. It would be of great help if you could tell me where I went wrong. Here is my code:

```
import math
import nltk
import json
import pymongo
#import sys
import nltk.corpus

from funcs import get_name_entity
from funcs import sentiment_analysis
from funcs import get_wordlist
from funcs import get_pos_tag

def get_post(count):
    data = ()
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)        #take data from database Mongo
    db = client.News_Updated                                #accessing the database News_Updated
    db.News_Updated.find()
    temp = []
    #print count
    if count == 0:
       data = db.ndtv
    elif count == 1 :
       data = db.timesofindia
    elif count == 2 :
       data = db.hindustantimes
    elif count == 3 :
       data = db.asianetnews
    elif count == 4 :
       data = db.khabarndtv
    #print data.find()

    for post in data.find():
        temp.append(post)
    return temp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    limit = -1
    while count < 5:
        data = get_post(count)
        count += 1
        for text in data.index(2):
            print text
```

However I am getting an output as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 43, in 
>       for text in data.index(2):
>   ValueError: 2 is not in list

here is a sample of data from mongodb.

> {u'url': u'62-year-old-woman-murdered-in-tamil-nadu-s-salem-510469', u'_id': ObjectId('53551ebf39b71c444a991341'), u'data': u"Salem, Tamil Nadu:In a daring daylight murder, a 62-year-old woman was killed by two youths for a gold chain in a busy commercial locality in Salem, Tamil Nadu, police said.Dhanlakshmi was behind the counter of her husband's small shop on Arunachalaachari street in his absence when the assailants slit her throat with a knife and fled away taking the gold chain she was wearing, they said.Arunachalaachari street, dotted with jewellery, vessels and textile shops, is considered a busy commercial locality of the district. The incident sent shock waves among the locals.Deputy Commissioner of Police A G Babu visited the spot."}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Vital tool for the python beginner (or beyond-beginner...): "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()".  Type the names of local variables into the debugger to find out which one doesn't contain what you think it should contain.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), `index()` retrieves the list index of the given element. In your case, that is `2`. The error you see is because there is no such element as `2` in your sequence (`data`).

Perhaps you wanted to use `data[2]`? It is not very clear from your question.